# How to return the date associated with each member of a sorted list in xts

Tags: r, xts

I have an xts object 'foo' containing the top 6 largest negative percentage changes in the value of the share price of a stock over a certain period. Using sort(foo) produces a list sorted by date, as shown below, but I want to sort the list based on the values.

`sort(coredata(foo))` gives me the list I expect, but returns the values without the associated index date value, as shown below. I would like a list in the format:

```
2008-11-07 -0.150
2008-11-06 -0.145
```

etc

I feel that some combination of `index()` and `which()` might work but haven't been able to produce anything useful. Any pointers gratefully received.

```
sort(foo)

   [,1]
2008-10-08 -0.105
2008-10-16 -0.119
2008-10-27 -0.109
2008-11-06 -0.145
2008-11-07 -0.150
2008-12-12 -0.121

sort(coredata(foo))
[1] -0.150 -0.145 -0.121 -0.119 -0.109 -0.105
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along the lines of this would give you the dates in the desired order:

```
 index(foo)[ order(coredata(foo)) ]
```

xts and zoo objects do not like to be displayed out of order, so I think you would need to coerce them to a less "order"-ly class:

```
> foo3 <- as.data.frame(foo)
> foo3[order(foo3$V1), ]
[1] -0.150 -0.145 -0.121 -0.119 -0.109 -0.105
> foo3[order(foo3$V1), ,drop=FALSE]
               V1
2008-11-07 -0.150
2008-11-06 -0.145
2008-12-12 -0.121
2008-10-16 -0.119
2008-10-27 -0.109
2008-10-08 -0.105
```

Comment: Thanks to both James and DWin; I learned something from both answers, DWin's was slightly easier to grasp for a beginner like myself. I was trying to avoid converting to a data frame but I guess it's not much of an issue given that performance is not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

As @DWin pointed out, the index must be ordered (zoo stands for "Z's ordered objects), so you can't un-order xts/zoo objects.

You can use the `fmt` argument to `coredata.xts` (as described in `?coredata.xts`) combined with `drop` to get a named vector that you could then sort like you want.

```
sort(drop(coredata(x,fmt=TRUE)))
# 2008-11-07 2008-11-06 2008-12-12 2008-10-16 2008-10-27 2008-10-08 
#     -0.150     -0.145     -0.121     -0.119     -0.109     -0.105
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the `print` method for `xts` imposes a date ordering, so you can not solve this by subsetting alone: compare `foo[1:2]` and `foo[2:1]`.

To get what you want you could try,

```
ord <- order(foo)
dat <- data.frame(x=coredata(foo)[ord])
rownames(dat) <- index(foo)[ord]
```

This would **not** be an `xts` object however.